# Read the all value presents in Hashmap

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have define List of HashMap and reading the response of JSON API . Currently able to read only one value from the list and I want to read all the values.

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> allids = response.jsonPath().getList("data");


        HashMap<String,Object> firstid = allids.get(0);  

        Object a =  firstid.get("country");

        System.out.println(a);
```

JSON Response in PostMan

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "alert": [
            {
                "message": "Success",
                "type": "success",
                "skippable": 1
            }
        ],
        "from_cache": 0,
        "is_data": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 6004,
            "airport_name": "Adampur Airport",
            "city": "Adampur",
            "country": "India",
            "iata": "AIP",
            "icao": "VIAX",
            "latitude": "31.4338",
            "longitude": "75.758797",
            "altitude": "775"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Iterate the list?

Comment: Do you want to get `id`, `airport_name`, `city`, `country` and ... `altitude` ?

Comment: Yes, all value then Assert with country value which I read from excel and pass it to the Rest Assured

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the context, you can iterate over the list and get the Map values

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> allids = response.jsonPath().getList("data");
for(int i=0; i<allids.size(); i++){
    HashMap<String,Object> firstid = allids.get(i);  
    String country = (String) firstid.get("country");
    String city = (String) firstid.get("city");
    String iata = (String) firstid.get("iata");
    String altitude = (String) firstid.get("altitude");
    //similarly get others
    System.out.println(country);
}
```

Comment: Also need to read the id, airport_name, city, country and ... altitude from response data.

Answer (score 0):

Just `forEach` on your `List` you will get `Map` and then get all your `Object` bu using `get` .

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> allids = response.jsonPath().getList("data");
allids.forEach(elem->{
        String country = (String) elem.get("country");
        String city = (String) elem.get("city");
        // and so on.
    });
```